# How to index data by elements of lists in columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have the following DataFrame (named `df2` later):

```
    recipe_id                                        ingredients
0        3332         [11307, 11322, 11632, 11338, 11478, 11438]
1        3333  [11322, 11338, 11632, 11314, 11682, 11478, 108...
2        3334  [11632, 11682, 11338, 11337, 10837, 11435, 113...
3        3335  [11149, 11322, 11532, 11996, 10616, 10837, 113...
4        3336  [11330, 11632, 11422, 11256, 11338, 11314, 114...
5        3812                      [959, 92, 3, 554, 12271, 202]
...
```

I want to create another DataFrame which will have following colums : `['ingredients', "recipe_id1", "recipe_id2", ..., "recipe_idn"]`, where n is total number of recipes in database. I did that with the following snippet:

```
columns = ['ingredient'] + (list(df2['recipe_id'].unique()))
ingredient_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
```

After i create this DataFrame (which i did already), and populate it (problem i'm having), output should look like this:

```
In [1]:
# Create and populate ingredient_df by some method
columns = ['ingredient'] + (list(df2['recipe_id'].unique()))
ingredient_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
ingredient_df = populate_df(ingredient_df, df2)
Out [1]:
In [2]:  
ingredient_df
Out[2]:
   ingredient  ... 3332 3333 3334 3335 3336 ...
...
   11322       ...    1    1    0    1    0 ...
...
```

In the example above, value at `(11322, 3334)` is `0` because ingredient 11322 is not present in recipe with id 3334.

In other words, I want for every ingredient to have mapping `(ingredient, recipe_id) = 1` if ingredient is present in that recipe, and `0` otherwise.

I've managed to do this by iterating over all recipes and trough all ingredient, but this is very slow. How can i do this in more robust and elegant way using Pandas methods (if this is possible at all)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        recipe_id=list('abcde'),
        ingredients=[list('xyz'),
                     list('tuv'),
                     list('ytw'),
                     list('vy'),
                     list('zxs')]
    )
)[['recipe_id', 'ingredients']]

df

  recipe_id ingredients
0         a   [x, y, z]
1         b   [t, u, v]
2         c   [y, t, w]
3         d      [v, y]
4         e   [z, x, s]
```

***method 1***

```
df.set_index('recipe_id').ingredients.apply(pd.value_counts) \
    .fillna(0).astype(int).T.rename_axis('ingredients')

recipe_id    a  b  c  d  e
ingredients               
s            0  0  0  0  1
t            0  1  1  0  0
u            0  1  0  0  0
v            0  1  0  1  0
w            0  0  1  0  0
x            1  0  0  0  1
y            1  0  1  1  0
z            1  0  0  0  1
```

***method 2***

```
idx = np.repeat(df.index.values, df.ingredients.str.len())
df1 = df.drop('ingredients', 1).loc[idx]
df1['ingredients'] = df.ingredients.sum()

df1.groupby('ingredients').recipe_id.apply(pd.value_counts) \
    .unstack(fill_value=0).rename_axis('recipe_id', 1)

recipe_id    a  b  c  d  e
ingredients               
s            0  0  0  0  1
t            0  1  1  0  0
u            0  1  0  0  0
v            0  1  0  1  0
w            0  0  1  0  0
x            1  0  0  0  1
y            1  0  1  1  0
z            1  0  0  0  1
```